# Tensorflow predicting same value for every row

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, prediction

I have a trained model. For single prediction I restore the last checkpoint and pass a single image for prediction but the result is the same for every row. Does anyone have a clue of what might be wrong?

This is the code for prediction:

[image]

And this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Why the output of softmax is like this? would you please provide some information about the input and output of your network?

Comment: The input is a 3 channel image, and the outpu is a numpy array of shape (256,256,2) where 2 is the number of classes that I have

Comment: what are two 256s?

Comment: the image dimension. I think I found the problem. I need my input to have shape of (1, 256, 256, 1), thats why I performed image = image[...,0][...,None]/255 but doing so changed all the values to 0

Comment: So answer to your question, people will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem. I need my input to have shape of (1, 256, 256, 1), thats why I performed image = image[...,0][...,None]/255 but doing so changed all the values to 0

Comment: can you elaborate on why you need that input shape? thanks